# Why do some words with similar meanings sound similar as well?

Tags: etymology, phonology, roots

I just noticed while writing a few examples of similar words that uncannily sound like each other phonetically.

**Examples:**
An example is the similar words: *“gleaming”*, *“glittering”, “glinting”*, and *“glimmering”*.

Also: “*repulsive*” and “*repugnant*” are interesting.

There are more words like this but I can’t think of them immediately on the spot. Obviously English is a rich language and thus one can find numerous examples seemingly showing different things, but is this to do with the roots of the words? As in, do they actually share the same etymology or are they just coincidental?

Comment: I thought initially that they would have the same etymologies but perhaps a couple centuries ago a couple of branches split up and different words arose from the same origin...this is intriguing.

Comment: They have the same PIE root _*ghel-_ meaning _to shine_: gild; glad; glance; glare; glass; glaze; glazier; gleam; glee; glib; glide; glimmer; glimpse; glint; glissade; glisten; glister; glitch; glitter; glitzy; gloaming; gloat; gloss; glow; glower; gold; guilder - [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ghel-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_52720)

Comment: Certain sounds provoke a particular emotion.  The leading "gl" sound seems happy and positive.  The "ab" sound seems negative.  Similarly with "rep".  Of course, partly this is because of their association with some of the above words, but partly the above words survived generations of word evolution because of the way they sounded.

Comment: Another example: [wer-(2)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*wer-) is the root from which many *wr-* words are derived, including wrangle, wreathe, wrench, wrestle, wriggle, wring, wrinkle, wrong and wry.

Comment: See also the possible duplicate [Sounds which seem to express a particular quality in whatever words they appear](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76876/sounds-which-seem-to-express-a-particular-quality-in-whatever-words-they-appear/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, all of your examples share the same etymology and can be traced back to the PIE root *ghel. As explained in [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ghel-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_52720) (emphasis mine):

> *ghel- (2)
>
> Proto-Indo-European root meaning "to shine;" it forms words for "gold"
>   (the "bright" metal), words denoting colors, especially "yellow" and
>   "green," also "bile, gall," for is color, and a large group of
>   Germanic gl- words having to do with shining and glittering and,
>   perhaps, sliding. Buck says the interchange of words for yellow and
>   green is "perhaps because they were applied to vegetation like grass,
>   cereals, etc., which changed from green to yellow."
>
> It forms all or part of: arsenic; Chloe; chloral; chloride;
>   chlorinate; chlorine; chloro-; chloroform; chlorophyll; chloroplast;
>   cholecyst; choler; cholera; choleric; cholesterol; cholinergic;
>   Cloris; gall (n.1) "bile, liver secretion;" gild; glad; glance; glare;
>   glass; glaze; glazier; **gleam**; glee; glib; glide; **glimmer**; glimpse;
>   **glint**; glissade; glisten; glister; glitch; **glitter**; glitzy; gloaming;
>   gloat; gloss (n.1) "glistening smoothness, luster;" glow; glower;
>   gold; guilder; jaundice; melancholic; melancholy; yellow; zloty.
>
> It is the hypothetical source of/evidence for its existence is
>   provided by: Sanskrit harih "yellow, tawny yellow," hiranyam "gold;"
>   Avestan zari "yellow;" Old Persian daraniya-, Avestan zaranya- "gold;"
>   Greek khlōros "greenish-yellow color,"  kholos "bile, gall, wrath;" 
>   Latin helvus "yellowish, bay," Gallo-Latin gilvus "light bay;"
>   Lithuanian geltonas "yellow;" Old Church Slavonic zlutu, Polish żółty,
>   Russian zeltyj "yellow;" Latin galbus "greenish-yellow," fellis "bile,
>   gall;" Lithuanian žalias "green," želvas "greenish," tulžis "bile;"
>   Old Church Slavonic zelenu, Polish zielony, Russian zelenyj "green;"
>   Old Irish glass, Welsh and Breton glas "green," also "gray, blue;" Old
>   English galla "gall, bile," geolu, geolwe, German gelb, Old Norse gulr
>   "yellow;" Old Church Slavonic zlato, Russian zoloto, Old English gold,
>   Gothic gulþ "gold;" Old English glæs "glass; a glass vessel."

---

The same principle holds for *repugnant* and *repulsive* both of which are derived from Latin words using the word forming element `-re` meaning ["back to the original place; again, anew, once more"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/re-). In the case of *repugnant*, the etymology (according to [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repugnant)) is (emphasis mine):

> repugnant (adj.)
>
> late 14c., "contrary, contradictory," from Old French
>   repugnant "contradictory, opposing" or directly from Latin repugnantem
>   (nominative repugnans), present participle of repugnare "to resist,
>   fight back, oppose; disagree, be incompatible," from re- "back" (**see
>   re-**) + pugnare "to fight" (from PIE root *peuk- "to prick"). Meaning
>   "distasteful, objectionable" is from 1777.

And that of [*repulsive*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repulsive) is:

> repulsive (adj.)
>
> early 15c., "able to repel," from Middle French repulsif (14c.) and
>   directly from Medieval Latin repulsivus, from repuls-, past participle
>   stem of repellere (see repel). The sense of "causing disgust" is first
>   recorded 1816. Related: Repulsively; repulsiveness.

While [*repel's*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/repel) is (emphasis mine):

> repel (v.)
>
> early 15c., "to drive away, remove," from Old French repeller or
>   directly from Latin repellere "to drive back," from re- "back" (**see
>   re-**) + pellere "to drive, strike" (from PIE root *pel- (5) "to thrust,
>   strike, drive"). Meaning "to affect (a person) with distaste or
>   aversion" is from 1817. Related: Repelled; repelling.

As you can see, both words can be traced back to the same `-re`.

So yes, for both the sets you mention in your question, the reason they sound similar is that they share similar etymologies. I believe it is this  shared origin which gives rise to the phonaesthetic effect described in [Decapitated Soul's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/532065/25030). The *reason* these words all sound similar is because of their shared etymology, and the *result* of this similarity is the phonaesthetic effect.

Comment: this can be taken a step further to ask why \*peuk and \*pel should be so similar, and indeed there is a bunch of roots that are most well known as reflected in prepositions, *off, of*, Gr. *epi-, apo*, etc. that also appear in verbs, e.g. Hittite *pai, paii* "to go" (by one account). However, these are not associated as far as I know, so one has to keep asking, alas, surely not etymonline that has \*pel with 5 different definitions from AHD, pokorny, etc, which is somewhat outdated now anyway.

Answer (score 17):

*Gleaming, glittering, glinting, glimmering, glisten* etc., sound similar and have closely related meanings because they share the same *phonaestheme* ***gl-***.

*Repugnant, repulsive, reprehend, repent, reprove* etc., can also be said to have a common phonaestheme ***rep-***.

#### Sound symbolism

A **phonaestheme** is a particular sound sequence that suggests a certain meaning. Words beginning with *gl-* are often associated with light reflection or vision: *glitter, glisten, glow, gleam, glare, glint, glimmer, gloss* etc., pertain to light. The study of phonesthemes is called *[phonaesthetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonaesthetics)* and the phenomena is called *[**phonesthesia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism)* or *[**sound symbolism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism)*.

David Crystal has explained it in Detail in [*The Ugliest Words*](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2009/jul/18/ugliest-words-michael-jackson-biographies). Here's an example from *The Ugliest Words* [modified & simplified]: Suppose you're in a spaceship approaching a different planet where there are two races. One of them is beautiful and friendly, the other is unfriendly and ugly. You also know that one of them is called *Lamonians* and the other is called *Grataks*. Which is which? David Crystal says that most people associate *Lamonians* with the friendly race and *Grataks* with the bad guys. He further says that it's all a matter of sound symbolism and that words having soft sounds (nasals & liquids, long vowels/diphthongs etc), reinforced by a gentle polysyllabic rhythm, are interpreted as "nicer" than words having harsh sounds (such as the velar plosives), short vowels and an abrupt rhythm.

### Examples

There are many other examples of phonaesthemes. Some examples are:

- #### *Sl-*

words starting with *sl-* are often associated with pejorative behaviours, traits, or events: *slack, slouch, sludge, slime, slosh, slash, sloppy, slug, sluggard, slattern, slut, slang, sly, slither, slow, sloth, sleepy, sleet, slip, slipshod, slope, slit, slay, sleek, slant, slovenly, slab, slap, slough, slum, slump, slobber, slaver, slur, slog, slate* etc. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme)]

- #### *Sn-*

words starting with *sn-* are related to mouth and nose: *snarl, sniff, sniffle, snuf, snoot, snout, snub, snot, [sneeze and snore](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/551453/365490)* etc. [[ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonestheme-word-sounds-1691505)]

- #### *Fl-*

these words are expressive of movement as in: *flap, flare, flee, flick, flicker, flounder, fling, flip, flit, flitter, flow, flutter, fly, flurry, flounce, flourish, flout, flail, flash, flex, flinch, flock, flop* etc. [[ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonestheme-word-sounds-1691505)]

- #### *Pr-*

related to human (social role) as in: *proud, prior, prophet, profit, proxy, prosper, pride, price, private, prize, precious, prelate, prep, praetor, prince, privy, priest, pro, pray, pram, prance, prattle, proffer, prom, prude, prompt, proper, prayer, prate, praise, prig, prim, primp, prink, prissy, pretty, preach, preen promise* etc. [[John Lawler's research papers](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf)] (I highly recommend reading it.)

- #### *Squ-*

(/skw-/) denotes discordant, eruptive sounds: *squeal, squeak, squash (quash), squall (scream discordantly) {variant of squeal}, squish {variant of squash}, squidge {variant of squish}, squitter, squirt, squawk (cry with a harsh note), squirk (half-suppressed laugh, squeak), squank* etc. [[English Phonaesthemes Dictionary](https://www.oocities.org/soho/studios/9783/phond1.html)]

- #### *-irl/-url*

related with circular as in: *twirl, curl, furl, burl, knurl, whirl, hurl, swirl, purl* etc. [[English Phonaesthemes Dictionary](https://www.oocities.org/soho/studios/9783/phond1.html)]

- #### *Cl-*

denote sound: *cluck, click, clap, clack, clash, clutter, clang, clank, clamber, clamour, clam, clump, clip* etc. [[English Phonaesthemes Dictionary](https://www.oocities.org/soho/studios/9783/phond1.html)]

- #### *G-* (/g/)

associated with throat: *gulch (swallow, devour greedily), gulp, gush, gaggle, giggle, gabble (jabber), gobble (said of turkey cock), gurgle, guggle, guttle (eat greedily), guzzle (swallow liquor greedily), gargle, gulch (ravine, cleft), gab (talk), gob (talk), gob (mouth, beak), guff (puff, whiff), guffaw* etc. [[English Phonaesthemes Dictionary](https://www.oocities.org/soho/studios/9783/phond1.html)]

- #### *Y-*

words starting with *y* can be associated with shouting, yelling, crying, chattering or other similar sounds as in: *yell, yelp, yap, yatter, yammer, yay, yowl, yesk, yawl, yip* etc. [[English Phonaesthemes Dictionary](https://www.oocities.org/soho/studios/9783/phond1.html)]

- #### *Ab-*

*ab-* can also be associated with negative meanings: *abhorrent, abhor, abrasive, absurd, abuse, abominable, abolish, abduct, aberrant* etc. [Source: myself]

---

#### References

- [Sound symbolism - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism)
- [Phonaesthetics - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonaesthetics)
- [Phonaestheme - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme)
- [John Lawler's research papers](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf)
- [English Phonaesthemes Dictionary](https://www.oocities.org/soho/studios/9783/phond1.html)
- [Phonaestheme - ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/phonestheme-word-sounds-1691505)

The following papers might also be of interest:

- [The Reality of English Phonaesthemes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309289841_The_Reality_of_English_Phonaesthemes)
- [Sound Symbolism – Berkeley UC](http://www.linguistics.berkeley.edu/%7Eohala/papers/SEOUL4-symbolism.pdf)

Comment: I've done a bit of work on the subject, as it happens. For example, [the `BL-` and `BR-` assonances](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf) (initial cluster phonesthemes), or the [`KL-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf). Rimes (syllabic nucleus plus coda phonesthemes) are equally interesting, but pattern differently, [as this handout shows](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/rimecoherencehandout.pdf). Full details [are available here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono).

Comment: (Typo: ... and the **phenomenon** is called phonesthesia...)

Comment: No, you're confusing the linguistic phenomenon with the physiological. Synesthesia is a characteristic of individual people; phonosemantics is a characteristic of individual languages.