# Relationship between sw- and w- phonesthemes

Tags: etymology, morphology

Consider the following pairs of English words:

- whirl - swirl
- whoosh - swoosh
- wipe - swipe (and maybe "sweep" too)
- wag - swag (as in the motion)
- wing - swing (maybe)

I am aware of phonesthemes from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532061/why-do-some-words-with-similar-meanings-sound-similar-as-well/) excellent question and associated answers. I am interested in relations *between* phonesthemes, like the one I illustrate above. I get the impression that phonesthemic boundaries are somewhat squishy, but it still seems like we might be able to identify precise patterns. My questions are:

1. **Is there a regular semantic relationship between w- words and their sw- counterparts, whenever they occur?** (For the record, only relation I can discern is *they mean kind of the same thing*. But if the relationship is so trivial, why should such pairs exist at all?)
2. **More generally, can phonesthemes be inflected in the same way that whole words can?**

Comment: This is probably a better question for [linguistics.se], since phonesthetics is somewhat universal, not specific to English.

Comment: What does 2 mean? How do you want to inflect phonesthemes? For number, gender, grammatical role, tense...?